# Why does X<T> not work but new X<T> works for a forwarded declared class template?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, g++

While composing an answer to [When can I use a forward declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553682/when-can-i-use-a-forward-declaration), I ran into an issue that I cannot explain.

```
// Forward declared class template:
template <typename T> struct X;

// Two other class templates that use it

template <typename T>
struct Foo {
   X<T>* m;
   Foo() : m(new X<T>) {}
};

template <typename T>
struct Bar {
   X<T> m;
};

// and a function that creates instances of Foo and Bar.

void test1()
{
   Foo<int> foo;
   Bar<int> bar;
}

// Define the class template after test1. On purpose.
template <typename T> struct X {};

int main()
{
}
```

When I compile the above program using g++ 4.9.3, I get compiler error for

```
Bar<int> bar;
```

but not for

```
Foo<int> foo;
```

Both require the definition of `X` since both fail to compile if omit the definition of `X`.

However, by just including the definition of `X` in the translation unit, `Foo<int> foo;` works while `Bar<int> bar;` does not work. Is this expected?

Comment: It's ill-formed, NDR.